# How can I link python embedded in a c/c++ application

Tags: python, c, linker

I would like to use python embedded in a c++ application.
Here is my code:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

I have included in the c:\log\python27\include to get Python.h and also c:\log\python27\libs to have the corresponding linked library of python which is installed in c:\log\python27
It's compiling but not linking... Why?
I always have followings errors:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_SetProgramName'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
```

Comment: Does this helps ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013441/how-to-link-c-lib-against-python-for-embedding-under-windows

Comment: It seems you are not providing the Python.h source file

Comment: No, I have exactly the same linking errors with your command! unbelievable I really don't know what to try now!!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple command if you are using python3.5

```
g++  test.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.5 -lpython3.5m -o call_function
```

depending where your libraries are!